# How we can add another 2nd stored procedure in in 1st stored procedure in condition wise

Tags: plsql

I want to understand the code logic, for below scenario

I have logic, I have 1 stored procedure that works when we need to rerun the task if data is invalid. But now I am writing another stored procedure for the same purpose but functionality is if data is invalid then it will take data from 2 tables then rerun the whole data.

Now for this 2 scenarios are there. Now I want add 2nd stored procedure in 1st stored procedure in if else condition how I can add.

If I want to take two table data to reprocess then it will take 2nd stored procedure else 1st stored procedure.

Comment: No clue what you are asking, but sounds like you want to put your procedures in a package?  It would be helpful if you edited your question and show an example with code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.